# Receiver naming consistency

Tags: go, naming-conventions

The official documentation recommands to use the same receiver name everywhere. But does it really make sense to comply with that?

I mean, I imagine something like `func (first Foo) concat(second Foo) (combinded Foo)` to be more expressive, while `first` does only make sense in that very context of concatenation. If we don't go that route, we're basically forced to resort to some agnostic but useless receiver naming like `f`, wasting an opportuniy for self-documenting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go Wiki: Receiver Names:](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names)

> The name of a method's receiver should be a reflection of its identity; often a one or two letter abbreviation of its type suffices (such as "c" or "cl" for "Client"). Don't use generic names such as "me", "this" or "self", identifiers typical of object-oriented languages that gives the method a special meaning. In Go, the receiver of a method is just another parameter and therefore, should be named accordingly. The name need not be as descriptive as that of a method argument, as its role is obvious and serves no documentary purpose. It can be very short as it will appear on almost every line of every method of the type; familiarity admits brevity. **Be consistent, too: if you call the receiver "c" in one method, don't call it "cl" in another.**

If you have a single method, it probably doesn't matter. If you have a type with many (maybe even dozens of methods), it does help if you use the same receiver name in all. It's much easier to read and understand.

Also if you want / have to copy some code from one method to another (refactoring), if the receiver name is the same, you can just do copy / paste and your done, you don't have to start editing the different names.

Also Dave Cheney: Practical Go: Real world advice for writing maintainable Go programs:

> #### [2.4. Use a consistent naming style](https://dave.cheney.net/practical-go/presentations/qcon-china.html#_use_a_consistent_naming_style)
>
> Another property of a good name is it should be predictable. The reader should be able to understand the use of a name when they encounter it for the first time. When they encounter a *common* name, they should be able to assume it has not changed meanings since the last time they saw it.
>
> For example, if your code passes around a database handle, make sure each time the parameter appears, it has the same name. Rather than a combination of `d *sql.DB`, `dbase *sql.DB`, `DB *sql.DB`, and `database *sql.DB`, instead consolidate on something like;
>
> ```
> db *sql.DB
> ```
>
> Doing so promotes familiarity; if you see a `db`, you know it’s a `*sql.DB` and that it has either been declared locally or provided for you by the caller.
>
> **Similar advice applies to method receivers; use the same receiver name every method on that type. This makes it easier for the reader to internalise the use of the receiver across the methods in this type.**

Also an interesting reading: [Neither self nor this: Receivers in Go](https://blog.heroku.com/neither-self-nor-this-receivers-in-go)

Comment: Thanks! I've read the Go Wiki, that's why I'm wondering. I do not really find that "This makes it easier for the reader to internalise the use of the receiver" very convincing. It's the very same receiver type right after the name. And the dogma shifts more and more to "naming is more important than the type" (that's why many languages have the name before the type nowadays), but we give that up if the name doesn't tell anything more than the type basically.

Answer (score 2):

Given that 1. You have a good method name, 2. The receiver type is readily apparent from the method declaration, most of the time a short name like `f` is quite alright. In the case where you need to differentiate the receiver from a parameter, it suggests that you could use a regular function rather than a method, since apparently the receiver doesn't have an obvious meaning that follows from the method name.

Comment: Yeah, a regular function is probably a good idea. I just find it's a waste of opportunities here. We're basically enforced to use a variable name which matches more or less the type name.

Comment: The rule is not exactly enforced as it's just guidance from the Go project. My guess for the motivation is that they saw many people using conflicting conventions like `this` and `self` from other languages causing both inconsistency, and unnecessarily long names in a majority of cases. It's not terrible to go against this rule sometimes, but if you have to do it *all* the time, I think it's evidence of other problems. Methods, by definition, should be strongly tied to **one** particular value (the receiver).  So, in general, you wouldn't expect the need to differentiate that value further.